# Minimax Algorithm Implementation In Python3

Tags: python, algorithm, implementation, tic-tac-toe, minimax

I have been trying to build a Tic-Tac-Toe bot in Python. I tried to avoid using the Minimax algorithm, because I was QUITE daunted how to implement it. Until now.
I (finally) wrote an algorithm that sucked and could lose pretty easily, which kinda defeats the purpose of making a computer play Tic-Tac-Toe. So I finally took the courage to TRY to implement the algorithm. I stumbled upon [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44089757/minimax-algorithm-for-tic-tac-toe-python) StackOverflow post. I tried to implement the chosen answer there, but I can't understand most of the stuff. The code in that answer follows:

```
def minimax(self, player, depth = 0) :
    if player == "o":
        best = -10
    else:
        best = 10
    if self.complete():
        if self.getWinner() == "x": # 'X' is the computer
            return -10 + depth, None
        elif self.getWinner() == "tie":
            return 0, None
        elif self.getWinner() == "o" : # 'O' is the human
            return 10 - depth, None
    for move in self.getAvailableMoves() :
        self.makeMove(move, player)
        val, _ = self.minimax(self.getEnemyPlayer(player), depth+1)
        print(val)

        self.makeMove(move, ".")

        if player == "o" :
            if val > best :
                best, bestMove = val, move
        else :
            if val < best :
                best, bestMove = val, move

    return best, bestMove
```

First of all, why are we returning `-10 + depth` when the computer win and `10 -
 depth` when the human wins? (I get why we return 0 when it is a draw). Secondly, what is the `depth` parameter doing? Is there some way to omit it?
*Should* we omit it?

I'm probably missing something fundamental about the algorithm but, I *think* I understand it well enough. Please bear in mind that I'm very new to recursive algorithms...

### EDIT

So, now I made myself the function:

```
def minimax(self, player):
    won = 10
    lost = -10
    draw = 0

    if self.has_won(HUMAN):
        return lost, None
    elif self.has_won(BOT):
        return won, None

    if not(self.board_is_empty()):
        return draw, None

    moves = self.get_available_moves()

    for move in moves:
        self.play_move(move[0], move[1], player)
        make_board(self.board)

        if self.board_is_empty():
            val, _ = self.minimax(self.get_enemy_player(player))
        self.rewind_move(move)

        if val==won:
            return val, move
```

But the problem now is I can't understand what happens when the move ends in a draw or a loss (for the computer). I think what it's doing is that it goes through a move's consequences to see if SOMEONE wins (that's probably what is happening, because I tested it) and then returns that move if SOMEONE wins. How do I modify this code to work properly?

Note:

- This function is in a `class`, hence the `self` keywords.
- `moves` is a list containing tuples. eg. `moves = [(0, 1), (2, 2)]` etc. So, moves contains all the empty squares. So each `moves[i][j]` is an integer modulo 3.
- I'm using the exhaustive algorithm suggested by Jacques de Hooge in his answer below.

Comment: 10 probably ensures that something coming out of a 9-element board is always nonzero.

Answer (score 0):

First note that 10 - depth = - (-10 + depth).
So computer wins have opposite signs from human wins.
In this way they can be added to evaluate the value of a gameboard state.
While with tictactoe this isn't really needed, in a game like chess it is, since it is too timeconsuming to try all possible combinations until checkmate, hence gameboard states have to be evaluated somehow in terms of losses and wins (losing and winning chess pieces, each worth a certain amount of points, values drawn from experience).

Suppose now we only look at 10 - depth (so human wins).
The most attractive wins are the ones that require the least plies (moves).
Since each move or countermove results in the depth being incremented,
more moves will result in parameter depth being larger, so 10 - depth (the "amount" of advantage) being smaller. So quick wins are favored over lenghty ones. 10 is enough, since there are only in total 9 moves possible in a 3 x 3 playfield.

So in short: since tictactoe is so simple, in fact the winning combination can be found in a exhaustive recursive search. But the minimax algorithm is suitable for more complicated situations like chess, in which intermediate situations have to be evaluated in terms of the sum of losses (negative) and gains (positives).

Should the depth parameter be omitted? If you care about the quickest win: No. If you only care about a win (with tictactoe): it can indeed be omitted, since an exhaustive search is possible.

[EDIT]

Exhaustive with tictactoe just means searching 9 plies deep, since the game can never last longer.

Make a recursive function with a parameter player (o or x) and a return value win or loss, that is first decided at the deepest recursion level, and then taken upward through the recursion tree. Let it call itself with the opposite player as parameter for all free fields. A move for the machine is the right one if any sequel results in the machine winning for all branches that the human may take on each level.

Note: The assumption I made is that there IS a winning strategy. If that is not the case (ties possible), the algorithm you have may be the best option. I remember with tictactoe the one who starts the game can always enforce a win in the way described above. So the algorithm will win in at least 50% of all games.
With a non-perfect human player it may also win if the computer doesn't start, if the human player does something suboptimal,

Comment: How would I implement such an exhaustive search in python?